# Can't assign volume controls to Logitech G500 Gaming Mouse

Tags: windows-7, mouse, logitech-mouse

I have a Logitech G500 Gaming Mouse, I've installed the software required to change the functions of the different buttons. All of the functions I attach to the buttons work correctly, excpt for changing the volume.

No matter what button I assign the volume controls to, the volume will not change when I click those buttons.

The mouse is abut 2 years old. It worked perfectly on my old pc, which was running Windows 7. And this morning, I brought the mouse into my office to use at my work pc, which is also running Windows 7 and now the volume controls will not respond.

I donwloaded the program you see in the screenshot below from the [Logitech support site](http://support.logitech.com/product/gaming-mouse-g500) this morning, so I'm up to date.

And after looking through some of the forums on the support site, I found [this question](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Logitech-G-Mice/G500-Volume-control-mapping-problems/m-p/817203#M13408), which is very similar to my own, but unfortunately has no answer...

[image]

Has anyone had a similar issue to me or does anyone ave any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is missing some details; **1)** Is this a first time install or was this working at some point previously? **2)** Have you ensured the mouse completely compatible with your PC and OS (which you haven't mentioned)? **3)** Have you browsed the [Logitech support](http://support.logitech.com/product/gaming-mouse-g500) site? **4)** Are you using the latest software? **5)** Have you tried it on another PC to see if the mouse is defective?

Comment: @CharlieRB Sorry! I'll update my question now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks CharlieRB for suggesting I look through the Logitech support site, *which I should have done anyway*. I found someone with an unrealted issue to mine, in the fix for their problem, someone explained that by switching the mouse from **On-Board Memory** to **Automatic Game Detection**, many of the mouses media features / functions *open up*. I don't know what they meant by open up, but I tried it and it resolved my volume control issue!

I added a screenshot of the option in case anyone ever has a similar issue. By default, it's set to **On-Board Memory**.

[image]